# Sorting a Dataframe column consisting of Sympy symbols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, sympy

I have a dataframe, where one column consists of Sympy symbols, and another column that consists of values.

```
import sympy as sym
import pandas as pd
d1,c,bc = sym.symbols("\delta, c, b_c")

values = [(d1,1),(c,2),(bc,3)]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['Symbol', 'Value'])
df['Symbol'].sort_values()
```

When I run the above, I get the error (which was expected, because Sympy symbols aren't sortable themselves, but the actual string contained is sortable.

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Sympy symbols are sortable if you can apply the .name method to them. I've done this with numpy arrays and lists of dictionaries:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array(values, dtype = [('Symbol','O'),('Value','O')])
values = sorted(values, key = lambda x: x['Symbol'].name)
display(values)
```

Output:

```
>>[(\delta, 1), (b_c, 3), (c, 2)]
```

I'm wondering if it's possible with dataframes because I'd rather not convert to a different format to apply a sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is more efficient but perhaps you could create a new column e.g 'Symbol_names'  for the data frame with names only and sort by that. You can always drop the column after

```py
df['Symbol_names'] = df['Symbol'].apply(lambda x: x.name) 

df = df.sort_values('Symbol_names')\
       .drop("Symbol_names", axis=1)\
       .reset_index(drop=True) # optional
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing this, thanks. Would be nice if there's a single line version, but this'll do :)